# Select DOM element by text from React component

Tags: javascript, jquery, testing, reactjs, jasmine

I'm testing a react component and need to simulate a click on a specific element inside the component. I don't want to add `id` just for the sake of the test, is there a way to select this element by text?

```
const ReactTestUtils = require('react-test-utils');
const Sidebar = require('components/sidebar');

describe('clicking on More button', function() {
  it('triggers analytics event', function() {
    const component = renderComponent(<Sidebar policyPreferences={ this.policyPreferences } />);

    const moreButton = component.getDOMElementByText('More'); // <- I need something like this
    ReactTestUtils.Simulate.click(moreButton);

    expect(analytics.track).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }
}
```

Comment: You could write a function that uses .innerHTML()

Comment: Thanks @ChrisWissmach. Any idea how I can select that element using `.innerHTML()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following function iterates through all elements until it finds one with the matching text:

```
function getElementByText(text){
    var all = document.getElementsByTagName("*");

    for (var i=0, max=all.length; i < max; i++) {
        if (all[i].innerHTML == text){
            return all[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```